# i need a function opencv in java return the percentage of the color in the mat , please

Tags: java, opencv, mat

i need a function opencv in java return the percentage of the color in the mat , please

```
public boolean procentage(Mat imageOne, int porsontageDeChangemnt) {
    boolean tr = false;
    int width = (int) imageOne.width();
    int height = (int) imageOne.height();
    int maxPixel = width * height;
    int cont = 0;
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

                double[] colorPixel = imageOne.get(i, j);

                if (((int) colorPixel[0] == 255)) {
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    int c = (int) ((cont * 100) / maxPixel);
    if (c >= porsontageDeChangemnt) {
        tr = true;
    }
    if (c > porsontageDeChangemnt) {
        tr = true;
    }
    return tr;
}
```

exception in this line   >> if (((int) colorPixel[0] == 255)) {

Comment: I take it from the fact you are ignoring any exception which would be thrown on that line that you mean it is a compiler error. Please describe what the error says.

Comment: Can you share the exception trace?

Comment: What is the exception? What are you passing into the function? Rather than telling us what you "need", please try asking a meaningful question. You'd get a better response from the stackoverflow community.

Comment: What is line 304

Comment: this is the exception : run:
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pfetp3.pkg0versionfinal.Methods.testSoustraction(Methods.java:304)    // line 304 is the test   if (((int) colorPixel[0] == 255)) {

Comment: line 304 is the test  if (((int) colorPixel[0] == 255)) {

Answer (score 0):

So you have not provided a full implementation but I slightly modified it to get something similar running.

If you break down your code all the way to the basic level and try something like this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++) {

        double[] colorPixel = null;  //This what your code thinks it is doing

        if (((int) colorPixel[0] == 255)) {
            System.out.println(colorPixel.toString());
        }
```

You will get the same exception on the same line you are currently.  The problem is you are passing a `null` value to `imageOne` in the method `procentage` at some point.

If you want to get a clearer answer you will need to ask a clearer question, since the exact problem is not shown in the code you have written here.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i resolve this problem with other way , with Bufferedimage class lieu Mat